# Ubuntu 12.04 freezes during installation

Tags: 12.04, installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 and when I select an option on the installation (example: Install Ubuntu), it suddenly freezes. I tried pressing keys, and it made this beep sound I do not recognize.

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bad download . . . try downloading the iso again.
It could be a bad burn on the cd or dvd . . . try burning it again at a slower speed.
It could be that you don't have enough system memory. Unlikely on any system newer than 6 or 7 years. You could download an "alternate installation" and try that.
It could be an unsuccessful transfer to a usb drive. I just tried installing 13.04 from a flash drive. The drive would boot a live session, but not install. Odd, I never did figure out why, but I used unetbootin again on a fresh download and it worked.